# Allow custom property camelCase pattern with regex

Tags: regex, string

I have this regular expression `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$` which forces me to use `--camelCase` pattern for CSS variables which i want.

But also i have issue and need to improve this regex to allow pattern with only one letter, like this: `--x`

How we can extend this regex, by also not breaking the `--camel-case` pattern?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to just make the second portion of the regex optional:

```
^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Now the minimum match is a single lowercase letter.  For match lengths of 2 or more, that lowercase letter may be followed by any alphanumeric character.